# CondaDependencyError: Cannot run solver. No functioning SAT implementations available

Tags: linux, solver

In the cluster system (Scientific Linux), I tried to create a new environment via conda. However, the following question occurs:

```
$ conda create --name py3 python=3.6
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: \ WARNING conda.common.logic:get_sat_solver_cls(278): Could not run SAT solver through interface 'pycosat'.                                                        failed

CondaDependencyError: Cannot run solver. No functioning SAT implementations available.
```

Any idea on this problem? Appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I resolved it by removing the conda directory and its associated path in my `~/.bashrc` script. I then reinstalled the latest version of Anaconda.

It seems that this was a bug for a while. There's a whole conda github issue that goes into more detail on this at https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7714#issuecomment-417553149.